# View, edit, only. No ability to upload documents at the site level

Tags: permissions, unique

I am trying to create a unique permission level at the site level for a group of users that can only view, and edit existing documents/lists, etc, but who cannot upload new documents.

Can you tell me what specific permission levels I need to apply.  Can a user return document they've edited?

Testing a site I thought contained the correct criteria does not let usesrs in the site at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open up the 'Read' Permission level and create a new one based on it (at the bottom there should be a button saying such). Just add the Edit Items checkbox and not the Add new and you should be good to go.